# Using a surveillance drive in a Web Server

Tags: web-server, hard-drive, advanced-format

Would there be any concerns about using a Surveillance/DVR, Advanced Format drive in a Linux Web Server.

Only wondering because I have 2x 1TB Seagate Video drives here that are now collecting dust and I need 2 hard drives for a server. So it would save me some money if I could just use those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DVR drives are tuned for sequential IO workloads. Random IO speeds will suffer if you use these, but depending on your load and IO profile, this may not be a problem.